# how can I usb tether between two android phones

Tags: usb, tethering, usb-tethering

I want to access the internet connection of my first android phone with my second android phone, via usb.

I am sensitive to wifi/network radiation emissions, so I want to connect the first phone via wifi or 3G network to the internet, and have internet access through a long usb cable, from my second phone, set on airplane mode.

I have a Galaxy S2 HD LTE SHV-120S Android version 4.0, rooted and stable
The second phone I have yet to purchase.
Are there apps to enable this? Drivers?

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759365/connect-two-android-phones-with-usb-cable). Perhaps, it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. In that situation, they wanted to have access to their second phone's files. I want to have access to the internet connection of the second phone. I am quite a novice at Android, so if you could suggest any settings, drivers, etc. I would appreciate it.